# command to search for files in a folder and move the files to different location

Tags: grep, find, cp, mv

```
I have a text file which has list of file names, I want to search these file names in a folder which has thousands of files and move the matching files to different location on linux.
```

Can some one help me with the command to do so.

Below is the code i am using

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/data.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    mv "/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/EDI855/$line" "/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/Final855" >/dev/null 2>&1
done <"$file"
```

Comment: how "big" is that *list of file names*?

Comment: The list has around 4000 file names

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
file="data.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        mv "/your/path/$line"  "/dest/path" >/dev/null 2>&1
done <"$file"
```

Comment: This is not working, how does read know from which file to read the data from in the above command

Comment: @user2231076 ..... see the 1st line in the code block, the `"data.txt"` was just an example.

Comment: Yes, I used my input file name as data.txt and did not work

Comment: @user2231076 "doesn't work" is not a good description, show a couple of lines from your file.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line
do
 mv "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/EDI855/$line" "/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/home/BILEKJ/Reprocess/Final855" >/dev/null 2>&1
done

I am running the script ./NewMove.sh data.txt

Comment: @user2231076 it won't work, You were not running my script. you changed the codes, and gave it a parameter, in a wrong way. You test first change the filename in codes, the `file` variable.

Comment: Hi kent, Thanks for ur help. I changed the code and added file variable file = 'data.txt' I did not give the full path as i am running the script in same directory

I am getting  line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

Comment: I was able to remove all the errors, the script is executing fine but the files are actually not moving to the destination location. I have update the code above